# My Multibit wallet is empty

Tags: multibit

I had a few bitcoins in a Multibit wallet version 0.5.14 on my old computer.  I decided to start up the old computer again and transfer the bitcoins to a hard wallet.  I opened it up and there's nothing in it.  The wallet appears to have synchronized.  I can remember before I used to input a password to see what was in my wallet but that option doesn't come up anymore.  Does anybody have any advice?  Please don't be too technical in your replies.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever write down your wallet words (seed phrase) or make a backup of the wallet?

Comment: I did write down the wallet words.  I didn't make a backup of the wallet.

Comment: I don's see anywhere to input those seed words.

Answer (score 1):

### Synchronisation status

First check Multibit's synchronisation status.

It probably shows a message on the bottom left status bar "`wallet synchronised with network`" (perhaps depending on exact version of Multibit software)

If it isnt synchronised yet, that *might* explain why it doesn't show the balance you expected.

---

### Recovery from wallet words

There are two main versions of Multibit: Classic and HD. Both are no longer supported.

To recover a wallet from your wallet words (also known as recovery phrase or seed phrase) follow the instructions at

https://multibit.org/help/hd0.1/restore-wallet.html

> From the unlock screen click the "Restore" button and follow the instructions on the MultiBit HD screen.

There may be different instructions for different versions of Multibit (Classic, HD2, HD3 etc) - check the appropriate instructions for your exact version if possible.

It may take a while (days) to synchronise before it shows you a balance.

---

### Multibit is unsupported

If your money becomes visible again, because Multibit wallet software is no longer supported, you should move your money into a different type of wallet. Multibit seem to suggest Electrum ([electrum.org](https://electrum.org/)) - maybe that is closest to Multibit in terms of user interface? However there are [many alternatives](https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet) which you should probably consider.

Consider a hardware wallet or an offline-wallet/cold-wallet for longer term storage.

Comment: Yes it is synchronised with the network.  I'll take a look at the recovery phrase information you sent.  Thanks.  I'll get back to you.  Possibly not today.  My version is Multibit 0.5.14   It's an early version as I understand.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Multibit Classic which never used seed phrases. If Multibit is not showing your balance then it has not loaded your wallet. You need to import the wallet backup or the key backups. You will find them in the Multibit directory.